# kill the process from ps command using single line

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Execute bat file from windows:

`ssh vagrant@192.x.x.x  -i f:\id_rsa "scss --watch %1| kill -9 (ps -aux | grep scss | cut -d " " -f 4 | head -n 1)"`

i want to kill the file after perform the scss command. OR can send a ctrl+c signal after the complete scss --watc.. command.

Comment: You want to kill what process after what happens? Does the `scss --watch` command terminate? Is the `scss --watch` command what you want to kill?

Comment: problem is that , this command take 2-3 sec. for execution and generate .css file but still exist entry in process table.

Comment: Assuming you meant `sass` and not `scss` there that would seem to be what `--watch` does. It watches for changes so it can rebuild. If you don't want that why are you using `--watch`?

Answer (score 1):

```
ssh vagrant@192.x.x.x  -i f:\id_rsa "scss --watch %1 && pgrep -f scss | xargs kill -9"
```

`&&` will block until the first command finish executing. and `pgrep` will grep the `PID` by keyword and use pipeline to send `kill` command to kill process.

Comment: Have you tried execute `pgrep -f scss | xargs kill -9` directly?